# wordpress, opening custom post shows empty taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

When I edit my post, no data is added to the taxonomy field (img 1) - although i know that i have chosen a taxonomy for it (img 2). So when i update the post, any previously entered taxonomies are dropped (added taxonomies still update the post, but wont show after update, repeating the mentioned behaviour).
Anyone have the slightest hunch to what would cause the data not to be entered?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I trailed the issue back to a few loops that i use in my edit, apparently there's issues with looping inside loops in posts. I found this https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18408 4 year old unresolved ticket explaining the behaviour. I resolved it by totally circumventing all that is WP loops and straight up querying what i need instead.